# Does EcmaScript have "reverse if notation"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

The normal way to write an `if`-statement is

```
if (a == b) {a=1}
```

but in eg. Perl it is possible to write the same as

```
a=1 if (a == b)
```

## Question

Is a similar syntax possible with EcmaScript?

Comment: No, ecmascript does not have that syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a specific statement to do that. You still have several options though

```js
if (a == b) {
  a = 1
}

if (a == b) a = 1      // No parenthesis

a == b ? a = 1 : null  // Using ternary operator
a = a == b ? 1 : a     // Using ternary operator
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the last one. Can you use different letters, s it e.g. sets `c=1`?

Comment: The last one has a ternary operator on the right side of the assignment (`=`). Basically, the result of the ternary operator `a == b ? 1 : a` is assigned to the variable `a`. If a and b are equals, a is assigned the value `1`. If they are different, a is self-assigned, i.e. it doesn't change